# How can limit the access to a directory and its subdirectories in PHP?

Tags: php, file-permissions

Hi I'm making some kind of file explorer on PHP and I'd like for example if I have a root folder like this:

```
/ (root)
|
|
|---home
      |
      |
      |---user
           |
           |
           |---folder
           |
           |---folder1
           |
           |---file1
```

Now how I would do so `user` would be only able to browse files inside /home/user/ and would not be able to do for example `cd ../../` and go outside? Thanks a lot :)
This is the code I use for the `cd`command:

```
<?php
function cd($actualdir, $dir) {
    //echo $actualdir.$dir."<br>";
    if($dir == "..") {
        $expdir = explode("/", $actualdir);
        $newdir = array_pop($expdir);
        $fulldir = "";
        foreach($expdir as $value) {
            $fulldir .= $value."/";
        }
        $fulldir = substr($fulldir, 0, -1);
        if($fulldir == "./rootfs/home") {
            return "permission denied";
        } else {
            return $fulldir;

        }

    } else {
        if(file_exists($actualdir."/".$dir)) {
            //echo $dir;
            return $actualdir."/".$dir;
        } else {
            return "no";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

BTW The root dir is just a directory on the web server root that should act as the system root for the shell

**EDIT:** Basically, if the user is `user` only allow him to enter to `/home/user` and its subdirectories. If the user is `test`only to `/home/test` and subdirectories. That's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)($fulldir) to let the filesystem resolve relative paths (like .. and symbolic links).

```
$fulldir = $actualdir . "/" . $dir;
$rootdir = "/home/user";
$length = strlen($rootdir);

$realdir = realpath($fulldir);
if ($realdir === false)
  return "file does not exist";

if(substr($realdir, 0, $length) != $rootdir)
  return "permission denied";

return "OK: $realdir";
```

Comment: That works half, because it stops `cd ..` but not `cd ../../`or similar :( Also that kills `cd ..`on allowed dirs

Comment: Did you try it on existing folder structures? I added a check for this just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ended doing this:

```
if(strpos($dir, "../../") !== false) {
        return $dir." not allowed";
    }
    if($dir == "..") {
        $expdir = explode("/", $actualdir);
        $newdir = array_pop($expdir);
        $fulldir = "";
        foreach($expdir as $value) {
            $fulldir .= $value."/";
        }
        $userlength = strlen($user);
        $finalength = strlen($user)+14;
        $userdir = substr($actualdir."/".$dir, 0, $finalength);

        $fulldir = substr($fulldir, 0, -1);
        if (strpos($fulldir, $userdir) !== false) {
            return $fulldir;

        } else {
            return "permission denied";
        }
```

Comment: oh, and what happens if I enter `../..`? Or `...` (win) ? or `./..`?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution? Don't let users *actually* navigate your file system. Represent it in the database if it's a document-uploading app or similar.

So you would have directories (categories) represented in a database, and files (items) for each category.